# Integrate xy in triangular region defined by three vertices.

Tags: integration

I have to find the area of the integrand $xy$ in the triangular region defined by the three vertices $(0,0), (5,0), (0,5)$.

This seems straight-forward. I drew my picture and came up with the following iterated integral.

$$
\int_0^5 \int_0^{\frac{-1}{5}x+5} xy\:dy\:dx\\
\begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^5 \left[ xy^2 \right]_0^{\frac{-1}{5}x+5}\:dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^5 \frac{x^3}{25} - 2x^2 + 25 x\:dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{x^4}{100} - \frac{2}{3}x^3 + \frac{25}{2} x^2 \right]_0^5\\
&= \frac{2825}{24}
\end{align}
$$

I even checked with wolframalpha and got the same answer, so I'm not quite sure what I'm not doing correct. I suspect that because my answer and wolframalpha's are the same, the culprit is probably my region. Looking at it, however, it does not seem wrong so I am unsure where my issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is the triangle $\{x,y\geq 0, x+y\leq 5\}$ then:
$$ \iint_T xy\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{5-x}xy\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{5}\frac{x}{2}(5-x)^2\,dx = \frac{625}{24}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hope this is the last time I ever have to ask for help on a region of integration problem. I doubt it, but it will be the last time this semester if nothing else.